# .bash_profile errors HomeBrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, homebrew

I'm struggling with a .bash_profile issue where when loading up a shell I immediately receive the following warnings.

```
Last login: Wed Nov  6 11:09:22 on ttys000 
-bash: /Users/Matthew/.bash_profile: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
-bash: /Users/Matthew/.bash_profile: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Matthews-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Matthew$
```

My .bash_profile is here:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`export PATH 
=/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-
1.9.3-p448/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-
1.9.3-p448/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/o
pt/ImageMagick/bin
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an extra `

This line:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`export PATH
```

should be

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7 export PATH
```